# Unity3D - Turning off a GameObject's guiTexture fails to respond

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I've been struggling with what appears to be a simple task for the past few hours. I have been successfully able to turn a GameObject's guiTexture on an off using `GameObject.guiTexture.enabled` as I have read in other similar questions. I do this in a script that is attached to the GameObject I wish to toggle.

The problem arises when I try to preform this same command from another script that is attached to an empty game object in my scene. When I interact with the button, simply nothing happens.

To give this some context, I am trying to create functionality to switch menus on the screen. When a user taps a certain UI button, I want to call `unloadMenu()` so I can wipe everything off the screen and draw the textures that belong to the appropriate menu.

```
//When the user lifts their finger
void OnTouchEnded ()
{
 switch (this.gameObject.name) 
 {
  //If they have selected the quiz button
  case "QuizButton":
    //this.guiTexture.enabled = false;
    //Call the unloadMenu function which will clear the GUITextures
    menuMgr.unloadMenu();
    break;
```

The commented out section is what works fine. But now, I wish to perform this code in a function that is located in another script - `menuMgr.unloadMenu()`

This is what the MenuManager script looks like:

```
public GameObject quizButton;
void unloadMenu()
{
  quizButton.guiTexture.enabled = false;
}
```

I have ensured to drag the quizButton gameobject from my scene into the inspector and connect it properly with the variable I have created yet nothing happens when this function is called. Does anyone have any idea why? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is there any error message generated? Or is it just simply not working?

Comment: Nope! No error messages are being generated. I threw a quick Application.Quit() in the unloadMenu function to test and that works just fine. The code is being executed, but I am not seeing any visual changes (the texture disappearing) in game.

Comment: It's almost as though any changes I make to quizButton in my MenuManager script do not effect the gameobject.

Comment: If there is no error and the result is not as expected, my thought is that you are modifying other `GameObject` instances. Can you please verify if this is the case?

Comment: when is the function `unloadMenu` called? how did you declare `menuMgr` variable?

Comment: @AldourCheng I am very new to Unity as you may have realized and so I'm not entirely sure how the best way to verify this would be. I can say however that I only have one instance of the QuizButton game object in my scene hierarchy and that is the one I am dragging into the inspector and attaching to my public variable.

Comment: @JayKazama `unloadMenu` is called when I lift my finger off of an existing `GUITexture` that I am rendering to the screen. I will add some comments to the code above. Through debugging I have confirmed that `unloadMenu` is being properly called and executed. It is being declared like so.

`public MenuManager menuMgr;
 void Start()
{
 menuMgr = new MenuManager();
}`

Comment: A `GameObject` instance named "QuizButton" consists of two components: `GUITexture` and `Script` containing the `OnTouchEnded()` function. Another `GameObject` instance which acts as your `MenuManager` contains only the `MenuManager` script. In the `Start()` function of the script attached to your "QuizButton", you initialize `menuMgr` with `menuMgr = new MenuManager();`. Have I got everything correctly? If that's the case, please refer to @JayKazama's answer.

Comment: @AldourCheng yes sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you declare `MenuManager` creates a new script while the reference to quizButton is in your MenuManager GameObject. That is why your `menuMgr.UnloadMenu` didn't do anything.
I have created something similar to yours and I found it worked fine :

Quizbutton Script:

```
public GameObject menuMgr; // reference to the empty game object (menu manager)
void OnMouseDown() // In your case, this is OnTouchEnded
{
    // get the script of menu manager here
    MenuMgrScript menuscript = menuMgr.GetComponent<MenuMgrScript>();
    // and execute the function you want
    menuscript.UnloadMenu();
}
```

Menu Manager Script:

```
// this script is exactly the same as yours, nothing's wrong here
// oh except add public to function UnloadMenu, so it can be called
// in the quizbutton script
public GameObject quizButton;
public void UnloadMenu() {
    quizButton.guiTexture.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks my friend. That was indeed the issue. I feel like it's these core concepts of Unity/C# that confuse me and bog me down every once a while. Coming from a VS/C++ background getting used to Unity has been quite a challenge for me. I'll be sure to keep this in mind for similar future scenarios.

Comment: Everyone was once a newbie :D